# 4 API-calls or one call that gets information from all 4 places

Tags: rest, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have a Vue application where I start with getting a lot of information to my $store.
I have a API-call where I get all "Books", another API-call where I get users "Bookmarks", another API-calls that get "Subjects" (all books a divided into subjects) and another API-call that gets all "Categories".

I recognize that all those API-calls takes a lot of time and resources. So I was wondering in how to do it more efficient.

1. Should I make a method GetAll()  that gets all of these different classes, return it to frontend and seperate them.
2. Should I keep calling 4 different APIs
3. Should I make a method GetAll() that calls the 4 different APIs.
4. Should I do something else.

My guts are telling me number 1 is the best solution, but I hoped to get it confirmed here. Or, better, there is a way I havent been thinking of that is better and you can save me a lot of work.

EDIT:
Important information is that I can connect to the MSSQL, so it is not an external API.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the calls separate. It's generally better to not group unrelated things together, keeping them versatile so they can be used separately. This goes for both the API endpoint structure and the front-end calls.

Comment: But an alternative is to keep all the apis, so I can later call them Independently.  But for onload of page (first time) call all four of them.

Comment: @GerryMM88 Yes, place all the calls in the method that runs on page load but I'd recommend not creating an endpoint that returns all.